# undefined method `has_many' for Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm getting this error :

```
undefined method `has_many' for #<Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder:0xb410d4c>
```

It work when I use it like this :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ressource do
    form do |f|  
        f.inputs do
            f.input :offer_id, :as => :hidden
            f.input :name
            f.input :category, :include_blank => false, :collection => Category.order('place ASC').all, :member_label => :to_label
            f.input :description, :input_html => {:class => 'editor'}
            f.input :price
        end
        f.has_many :roles do |app_f|
            app_f.inputs do
                if not app_f.object.id.nil?
                    app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Supprimer l'utilisateur du lot"
                end
                app_f.input :user, :member_label => :to_label, :label => 'Assigné le lot'
                app_f.input :name, :include_blank => false
            end
        end
        f.buttons
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work in a partial, i need to call the has_many method by a different way or something else ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ActiveAdmin extends formtastic with some useful helpers such as `has_many` (`lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb` in the activeadmin gem).

Unfortunately, these helpers are not available by default in your templates.

Here are two options:

1. If you don't need the extra `has_many` functionality (it looks like active_admin adds some javascript to make it easy to add a new record to the collection), then you can use stock formtastic. This example should work fine in the activeadmin file as well as in a partial:

   ```
   ActiveAdmin.register Ressource do
     form do |f|  
       # ...
       f.inputs :for => :roles do |app_f|
         # ...
         app_f.input :name, :include_blank => false
       end
       f.buttons
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use the ActiveAdmin form builder explicitly:

   ```
   <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @resource], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>
     <!-- ... -->

     <%= f.has_many :teachers do |app_f| %>
       <%= app_f.inputs do %>
         <!-- ... -->
       <% end %>
     <% end %>

     <%= f.buttons %>
   <% end %>
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used option two as I want to add child items using a jQuery UI Autocomplete input area. It seems that the partial now has access to the has_many helper, but it now says undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass for the has_many when trying to create a new field. Any ideas what may be causing this? I'm suspecting one needs to do a .build in the controller?

Comment: Never mind, I had to use accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model for it to work properly. :)

Comment: This fixed the first error for me, but now I get a "can't modify frozen String" error on the line that create the has_many. Any ideas?

Comment: @elsurudo That sounds like a different issue. Maybe post a new question with a stack trace and more information...

Comment: I having such problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996966/no-implicit-conversion-of-activesupportsafebuffer-into-integer with has_many..(

Comment: 1+ for `builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder` this is what I was searching for since 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution

```
form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
end
```

Or, if you want to use partial:

```
<%= active_admin_form_for [:admin, @resource] ,:html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>
<% end %>
```