# ActiveAdmin Form with 2 models (belongs_to and has_many) don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have the following code form my passport_visas.rb model

```
ActiveAdmin.register PassportVisa do

  menu :label => "Visas"
  form :partial => "form"

  index :title => "Visas"
end
```

And this is my code for the partial "form"

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @passport_visa] do |f| %>

  <%= f.inputs "Main information" do %>
            <%= f.input :country %>
            <%= f.input :citizenship, :as => :radio, :collection => {"US Citizen" => 0, "Foreign National" => 1} %>
            <%= f.input :visa_type, :as => :select, :collection => ["Tourist", "Business", "Official"] %>
            <%= f.input :visa_required, :label => "Is Visa Required?", :as => :radio, :collection => {"Required" => 0, "Not Required" => 1} %>
            <%= f.input :maximum_stay, :label => "Maximum Stay" %>
  <% end %>

  <fieldset class="actions">
    <ol>
        <li class="action input_action" id="passport_visa_add_new_entry">
            <input name="new_entry" type="button" value="Add New Entry">
        </li>
        <li class="action input_action" id="passport_visa_remove_entry">
            <input name="remove_entry" type="button" value="Remove Entry">
        </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>

  <!-- Problem -->
  <%= f.inputs "Entries" do %>
    <%= f.has_many :visa_entries do |entry| %>
            <%= entry.input :type_of_entry, :as => :select, :collection => ["Testing"] %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.actions %>

<% end %>
```

And I'm getting this error message: "undefined method `has_many' for #Formtastic::FormBuilder:0x10c234c38"

I'm trying the entire day to setup this form, here's my model's code:

**passport_visa.rb**

```
class PassportVisa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visa_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :visa_entries
end
```

**visa_entry.rb**

```
class VisaEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :passport_visa
  attr_accessible :type_of_entry, :maximum_validity, :embassy_fees, :service_fees, :processing_time
end
```

Comment: Anybody? Please help me!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070779/undefined-method-has-many-for-formtastic

Sounds like a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a work around for that. So here's what I did to make it work:

1. First I got rid of the _form partial, because for some reason the "has_many" don't work inside there.
2. I modified my 2 models:

**passport_visa.rb**

```
class PassportVisa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visa_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :visa_entries
  attr_accessible :visa_entries_attributes, :country, :citizenship, :visa_type, :visa_required, :maximum_stay
  validates_presence_of :country, :citizenship, :visa_type, :visa_required, :maximum_stay
end
```

**visa_entry.rb**

```
class VisaEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :passport_visa
  attr_accessible :type_of_entry
  validates_presence_of :type_of_entry
end
```

And the last part, the actual form:

```
form do |f|

        f.inputs "Entries" do
            f.has_many :visa_entries do |ff|
                ff.input :type_of_entry, :as => :select, :collection => ["Testing"]
            end
        end

        f.actions

    end
```

Bye!