# no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, partial, formtastic

Here is my partial `_new_post.html.haml`:

```
= semantic_form_for Post.new, as: :post, url: client_panel_discussion_posts_path(resource), html: { data: { discussion_posts_url: client_panel_active_submission_discussion_url(resource.client_application, id: resource.slug) }, multipart: true}, builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder, remote: true, method: :post do |f|
  =f.inputs do
    =f.input :body
    =f.has_many :attachments do |a|
      =a.input :s3_url, as: :hidden, input_html: { class: "s3_url" }
      =a.s3_file_field :attachment, as: :file, class: 'js-s3_file_field'
```

Problem is that I get following **error**: `no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer into Integer` pointing to this  `=f.has_many :attachments do |a|` line.

If I remove `builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder` I get `undefined method 'has_many' for #<Formtastic::FormBuilder:0x007fda897dfc88>` error.

Anyone faced something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, as it occurred later, the solution was simply to run `bundle update activeadmin`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no FormHelper `has_many`.

It seems, you want to create fields for a `has_many` association. The Helper for that is `fields_for`.
Try:

```
= semantic_form_for @post, as: :post, url: client_panel_discussion_posts_path(resource), html: { data: { discussion_posts_url: client_panel_active_submission_discussion_url(resource.client_application, id: resource.slug) }, multipart: true}, builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder, remote: true, method: :post do |f|
  =f.inputs do
    =f.input :body
    =f.fields_for :attachments do |a|
      =a.input :s3_url, as: :hidden, input_html: { class: "s3_url" }
      =a.s3_file_field :attachment, as: :file, class: 'js-s3_file_field'
```

I didn't try it. I don`t know s3_file_field.

If you want to add/delete several attachments: there is a good [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) on this topic an have a look at the [gem cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Comment: hey, thx for reply!! It was silly of mine - I've tried fields for, not fields_for :D Still it is not working, it doesnt show anything, doesnt add any html - as if no code were written.

Comment: do you have any attachments already? field_for doesn't show field for new attachments (unless you manually built a new attachment on Post.new)

Comment: Yea, I've got it in my new action    def show
      post = Post.new
      post.attachments.build
    end (nevermind it's in show, it's because I build it in different controller) I actually want to allow user to add attachments to post

Comment: thank you so much! I am about to accept/upvote the answer, because I can now see the button to attach the files, last important thing - how can I actually allow user to attach more then one attachment?

Comment: I added two links to my answer covering this topic.